# Tensorflow gradient of loss with respect to model output gives None

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradienttape

I'm trying to differentiate my loss function with respect to the model output in the `training_step` function of a `tf.keras.Model`. This is my attempt:

```
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape1:
            y_pred, dense_out = self(x, training=True)
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
                tape2.watch(y_pred)
                loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred)
        dy = tape2.gradient(loss, y_pred)
```

I would use `tape1` for gradients I need later. First of all, `dy` gives `None`, how can I fix this? Secondly, is it allowed to return two output values when `training=True` in the  `call`-method of my model and only one when `training=False`? Even if I don't do this `dy` is `None`?

***Edit***: If I do the following outside the `train_step` function, It does give a result different from `None`:

```
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred, dense_out = model(x_train, training=True)
        loss = loss_fn(y_train, y_pred)
    print(tape.gradient(loss, y_pred))
```

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solutions now?